# How to multiply every digit of float input by user and then summing up

Tags: python-3.x

Hello i want to access float input by users and then multiply every other element of input as per Luhn algorithm but getting below errors. Any help is highly appreciated

```py
def main():

    while True:

        x = get_float("user_input: ")
        if(len(str(x))>12 and len(str(x))<20):
            break
        #multiply every other digit
    #for digits in x:

        y = str(x)
        y[0::2]= [z*2 for z in y[0::2]]
        print(y)
```

running the program

```
user_input: 1234567891234
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "credit.py", line 22, in <module>
        main()
    File "credit.py", line 13, in main
        y[0::2]= [z*2 for z in y[0::2]]
    TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Answer (score 1):

you cannot change only a portion of `y`, because it is immutable (string).

instead, you can do this

```py
y = "".join([str(int(z) * 2) if i % 2 == 0 else z for i, z in enumerate(y)])
```

this works because it reassign the variable `y` and not individual characters in `y` (which you cannot do)

Comment: while True:

    x = get_float("user_input: ")
    if(len(str(x))>12 and len(str(x))<20):
        break
Thanks, if i want to double and add the every digit after this without converting it into string, is there a way?

Comment: it is already a string, so you can do `s = sum([int(i) for i in y[::2]])`

Comment: Thanks mate but first i need to double the every other digit of user input which is between 13 to 19 digits

Comment: that's what the code I wrote in the answer does, just replace the `y[0::2]...` line in your code with that

Comment: Thanks i got that

Comment: now how to add every two digit number in resultant y?

Comment: i have to multiply from index 1 i.e every ther digit

Comment: @MannawarHussain `s = sum(map(int, y[::2]))`

Comment: thanks, its working fine for 13 digit user input but for 14 digit it is raising error, as i defined earlier user input could between 12 to 20. can you put insight

Comment: i want to double every other digit so i bit changed the code to this  y = "".join([str(int(z) * 2) if i % 2 == 1 else z for i, z in enumerate(y)]) but working fine for 14 digit user input while for 13 digit user input it is showing ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: